# Sort data and copy to matching sheet based on drop-down list in Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I get regular large data sets in Excel containing ~2000 names and demographic information, sorted by "caseload". I've built a macro to automatically format the data, create a list of unique caseloads (Sheet titled CaseloadList), then use that to create new sheets by caseload number (each caseload gets its own sheet).

Then I built a second macro that opened up the primary sheet, sorted by caseload, copied those people over to the specified caseload sheet, turned the data into a table, and then moved on to the next caseload. This macro works great with two major flaws - if the report I'm running the macro on has different caseload numbers, or a different number of caseloads, it hits a script error.

My code looks like this -

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
        "6800"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("6800").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This sorts by caseload 6800, copies the data, moves to sheet 6800, pastes the data in. However, if caseload 6800 doesn't exist in that particular report, then it hits a script error. If caseload 6801 is in the report, but wasn't part of the initial list when I recorded the macro, it gets left out.

What I would like to be able to do is have my code only use the options in the Caseload dropdown in the table to sort and copy over. These options are identical to the options in CaseloadList, which was used to create the new sheets.

I can post a full work book of this if that's easier to work with.